# Creating and exposing SOAP webservice in servicemix over network

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I have a webservice wsdl which im accessing through soap ui to send request and get response. I want to change this wsdl and deployed in servicemix so that same webservice is exposed by my servicemix. 
Below is the route

```
from(cxf:myEndpoint)
.to(cxf:realEndpoint)
```

Once deployed, im able to access the wsdl url in my system. Other system doesnt recognise my exposed webservice. Am i doing something wrong??

Comment: Do you want to proxy the service as is on ServiceMIx? or do you want to alter the service?

Comment: Proxy service is working fine. I want to alter the wsdl according to my need and expose it to another system so that some common functionalities works same.

Comment: Then you need to implement the wsdl and do alteration in code. Search for wsdl/contract first development with cxf on googpet.